# error in gradle sync error 24,13

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

hello I'm a beginner in android programming
when I want to run my app in android stadio I get an error in gradle sync
Error(24,13) failed to resolve:com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL42Y.png)

Comment: Don't post information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have android support library installed and/or in the gradle offline mode.

You can:

- Disable gradle offline mode to let android studio install the support library (From File->Settings->Gradle->Offline Mode)
- Install android support library from SDK Manager

Comment: I have installed support library but it still give error

Comment: Then you are not using the right version. You are using v23, check your SDK manager to see that does it match with the installed version ?

Comment: I didn't get your help